# Add element from one DOMDocument to another one PHP

Tags: php, domdocument

I have 3 DOMDocuments,

```
$legacyDomDocument1 = new DOMDocument();
$legacyDomDocument2 = new DOMDocument();
$legacyDomDocument3 = new DOMDocument();
```

I want to get the same element of this three documents and remove some childs.

```
$standortName = $legacyDomDocument->getElementById('produkt_title');
$standortName->parentNode->removeChild($standortName);
$standortName = $legacyDomDocument2->getElementById('produkt_title');
$standortName->parentNode->removeChild($standortName);
$standortName = $legacyDomDocument3->getElementById('produkt_title');
$standortName->parentNode->removeChild($standortName);
```

I also fetch a navbar from the first DOM.

```
 $rs = $legacyDomDocument->getElementById('submenue');
```

I can easily add the submenue.

```
$r->appendChild($rs);
```

But I still got problems adding the elements from the other two DOMDocuments.

```
$import = $legacyDomDocument->importNode($legacyDomDocument2, true);
$legacyDomDocument->appendChild($import);
$import = $legacyDomDocument->importNode($legacyDomDocument3, true);
$legacyDomDocument->appendChild($import);
```

What am I doing wrong? 
After using saveHTML the browser says:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::importNode() [domdocument.importnode]: Cannot import: Node Type Not Supported in /is/htdocs/wp1175221_C648A6HQST/www/v9/legacyParser/index.php on line 82
```

Line 82 is my import part above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Forget some code:
 $r->appendChild($pc1);
 $r->appendChild($pc2);

Comment: You're trying to import a DOMDocument instance, that doesn't work. What do you actually want to import?

Comment: Oh, forgot to add add it.

all three DOMs have the same div ('content_produkte') with several informations which I want to add to the first dom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One cannot import `DOMDocument` directly: you should go a bit deeper in hierarchy, using [documentElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.documentelement) property instead (that gives you a `DOMElement`):

```
$import = $legacyDomDocument->importNode($legacyDomDocument2->documentElement, true);
```

BTW, looks like it's appropriate to use `documentElement` when appending too:

```
$legacyDomDocument->documentElement->appendChild($import);
```

Here's [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/tR2ec) illustrating the concept. Note the difference when you drop the intermediary `documentElement`: the second document's contents are basically inserted adjacent to the root node, and that's hardly the desired outcome.

Comment: This tipp helped me a lot. Thanks.